# Arrays as Class Variables, Set in Constructs in Class

Tags: php, arrays, oop

Is there a way to pass an **array** to a class/object construct and access/return it or manipulate it?

Code:

```
$affiliates = array(
        "clickbank" => "clickbankdata",
        "meepbank" => array(
                "meepbankdata" => "meep"
        )
);
class Affiliate {
    public $affiliates = array();

    public function __construct($array) {
        $this->affiliates = $array;
    }

    public function getAffiliatesArray() {
        return $this->$affiliates;
    }
}

$main = new Affiliate($affiliates);
print_r($main->getAffiliatesArray());
```

Comment: I don't see the actual question in here. Doesn't that code already do what you want?

Answer (score 3):

```
   public function getAffiliatesArray() {
            return $this->$affiliates;
        }

   should be

  public function getAffiliatesArray() {
        return $this->affiliates;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
return $this->$affiliates;
              ^
              |-------- Remove This
```

With

```
return $this->affiliates;
```